# Problem when transferring over a file using cpp-httplib

Tags: c++, qt, curl

On linux, I'm using https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib to set up a simple REST server as a student project. One of the things it has to do is receive a file and scan it locally. I implemented a function for a post request it like such:

```
svr.Post("/scan", [&](const httplib::Request& req, httplib::Response& res){
    std::string body = req.body;

    qDebug() << "Creating local file...";
    QTemporaryFile inputFile;
    inputFile.open();
    qDebug() << "Writing to local file...";

    if(inputFile.write(body.c_str()) != -1){
        qDebug() << "Writing finished. Closing local file...";
        qDebug() << "Scanning local file...";
        QCryptographicHash hash(QCryptographicHash::Algorithm::Sha1);
        hash.addData(&inputFile);
        qDebug() << "hash: " << QString::fromStdString( hash.result().toHex().toStdString() );
        res.set_content(myEngine.scan(inputFile).toJson().toStdString(), "text/plain");
    }else{
        res.set_content("Failed to write file", "text/plain");
        qDebug() << "Failed writing. Closing local file...";
    }
    inputFile.close();
});
```

What happens is that I create a temporary file with QT, open it, the use its write() function to write request's body into the file. After I have written into it, I write out it's SHA1 has for debug purposes, then scan it with the 'myEngine.scan()' function. The 'myengine.scan()' function returns a JsonDocument containing the scan results, which I convert to a string send as a reply.

Now, the 'myEngine.scan()' works as intended, it basically just cheks if the file's hash is contained in a database.

Then I use curl to send a request:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary "@music_video.mp4" localhost:1234/scan
```

When I send a simple file, such as a .sh runnable script or a .txt text file, the file goes over, it gets scanned, returns the expected values, all good. The hash code at the server side is identical to the hash code on the client side.

However when I send over a .mp4 media file or a .png screenshot file, then the hash code at the server side is different then the hash code at client side. The QTemporaryFile at the server side is corrupted and differs from the client side file, therefore the scan result is not the expected result.

Tried it with postman, and the results are the same.
Tried messing around, such as using

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" --data-raw "@screenfetch.png" http://localhost:1234/scan
```

and other, similar variations, but the results are the same. The .mp4 file and the .png file is corrupted at the server side, while the .txt and the .sh files arrive without a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing into your temporary file, you use:

`inputFile.write(body.c_str())`, which uses `QIODevice::write(const char*)` ([doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write-1))

> Writes data from a zero-terminated string of 8-bit characters to the
>   device. Returns the number of bytes that were actually written, or -1
>   if an error occurred

You can assume that the file you are posting surely contains at least one byte equals to 0. Nothing is written after it is encountered, and you only write a truncated version of the original file in the temporary one.

You should use `QIODevice::write(const char *data, qint64 maxSize)` ([doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write)) like this:

```
if (inputFile.write(body.c_str(), body.size()) == body.size()) {
    // The temporary file has been written
}
```